# Why doesn't this regular expression match?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl script from Squid web proxy:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$|=1;
while (<>) {
    @X = split;
    $x = $X[0];
    $_ = $X[1];
    if (m/^http:\/\/([0-9.]{4}|.*\.youtube\.com|.*\.googlevideo\.com|.*\.video\.google\.com).*?\&(itag=22).*?\&(id=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/) {
        print $x . "http://video-srv.youtube.com.SQUIDINTERNAL/" . $2 . "&" . $3 . "\n";
    # youtube Normal screen always HD itag 35, Normal screen never HD itag 34, itag=18 <--normal?
    } elsif (m/^http:\/\/([0-9.]{4}|.*\.youtube\.com|.*\.googlevideo\.com|.*\.video\.google\.com).*?\&(itag=[0-9]*).*?\&(id=[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/) {
        print $x . "http://video-srv.youtube.com.SQUIDINTERNAL/" . $2 . "&" . $3 . "\n";

    } else {
        print $x . $_ . "\n";
    }
}
```

that I got from http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/DynamicContent/YouTube.
I've tested input such as

```
http://v24.lscache6.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Calgorithm%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Coc%3AU0hPRVFUTl9FSkNOOV9JTlJF&fexp=905230%2C901013&algorithm=throttle-factor&itag=34&ipbits=0&burst=40&sver=3&signature=2A5088FD4F64CF9D58A5B798E14452D71B51BAE8.2EABF06D09C8C81650266C5464CF1D0B4D6C25CC&expire=1300190400&key=yt1&ip=0.0.0.0&factor=1.25&id=e838f2cd3549e3cb
```

in RegexBuddy with Perl syntax, and I see it match the second regular expression in above script. But it didn't match when I ran the script. I'm not a Perl programmer, so where was I wrong?

Comment: There must be a module to parse URLS more easily (and more accurately). But that's not the point. Are you sure that your URL is the second field in your line? Because `$_ = $X[1];`.

Comment: Indeed, the `URI` module - and even if you don't use that, it may be a good idea to split the matching into several stages, this makes it possible to trace the cause of mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to divide the regex in separate variabales then modify one of them at a time. This way you can find the problem yourself.

I am not sure if someone will bother to debug your programm.
Example:

```
 my $part1 =qr/http:\/\/([0-9.]{4}/;
 my $part2 = qr/.*\.youtube\.com/;
 #etc ... then
 if (m/^part1|$part2....
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [URI parser module](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.58/URI.pm)?  Here is a [simple example](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch04_01.htm) using one. That way you can grab the host out by a simple `$uri->host()` and check it against your list of hosts. You should also be able to get the `itag` and `id` fields too regardless of what order they're in, or if there are other attributes as well, which could break a regex.

Comment: I'm not a perl programmer :P, that script, just the thing I meet when try to setup my squid server to cache youtube dynamic content.